# multi-upload images in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

which is the best way to handle multi-upload via AJAX in a RoR 3 app?
I read a lot of stuff about swfupload, pupload and so on, a suggestion about the best way to attempt is welcome!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

have you tried swfupload?
Its easy to use with rails3 + paperclip/attachment_fu

The article is written with rails 2 there are small fixes that you need to do then this will work fine. Take a look on following link.

http://jimneath.org/2008/05/15/swfupload-paperclip-and-ruby-on-rails.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with Uploadify + Carrierwave.

Here is a good tutorial for a Rails 3 application:
[Multifile upload with uploadify and carrierwave](http://blog.assimov.net/post/4306595758/multi-file-upload-with-uploadify-and-carrierwave-on)