# paperclip uploadify error Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip, uploadify

I am having issues with uploadify (with paperclip) for more than 2 weeks now. Paperclip on its own works beautifully but when I extend that functionality to multiple files upload (at a time) it doesn't do anything. I don't even see the files in the parameters in the terminal window.

I have uploaded a sample project in git https://github.com/inawlaljar/Paperclip-plus-uploadify

I am using rails 3.1 and mysql

Please help.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: But it sounds like Uploadify at least initiates a request to the server. Have a look at http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/onerror/ and try logging the error to console.log

Comment: i don't get any errors... I don't know whether it initiates a request to the server... any idea how to check pls?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post i suggest you to use SWFupload instead of uplodify;
[multi-upload images in ror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527081/multi-upload-images-in-ror/7528742#7528742)